# How to disable HTML Video Player playback speed / three dots

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I don't want to show playback speed in my video, is there any controls or `controlList` properties to disable that option like `controls disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://wicg.github.io/controls-list/html-output/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-media-controlslist) only three options are available (`nodownload`, `nofullscreen`, and `noremoteplayback`) and none seems to do what you want.
And you can't style the browser's default control set, but you can use the (JavaScript) Media API to build your own control set which of course you can style in any way that you like.
See [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/bgamaj).

Answer (score 17):

Add the parameter 'noplaybackrate' to controlsList.  It works for me.

Comment: In Chrome version 104, users can still right-click on the video and choose "Show all controls" to bring the playback speed menu back, and this doesn't work in Firefox, look at my answer for a way to force your desired playback rate by using JavaScript.

Answer (score 13):

you can add the following:

```
video.controlsList = "noplaybackrate";
```

however if you want to deactivate others as well, then as such:

```
video.controlsList = "noplaybackrate nodownload"
```

and you have the last one in the list "Picture in Picture"

disable this one as such:

```
video.disablePictureInPicture = true;
```

now your three dots are gone

and to be complete to also disable the full screen function

```
video.controlsList = "noplaybackrate nodownload nofullscreen"
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Chrome version 104 adding `noplaybackrate` to `controlsList` hides the "Playback Speed" from the menu, but users can still right-click on the video and choose "Show all controls" to bring it back!

Additionally, adding `noplaybackrate` to `controlsList` doesn't work in Firefox as of version 103.

What I did to force my video to play at regular rate (1) is to subscribe to `onratechange` and bring it back to the playback rate that I want as below:

```
let video = document.getElementById(mediaElementId);

video.onratechange = function () {
    video.playbackRate = 1;
};
```