# HTML audio controls - How to remove 3 dots from default audio player?

Tags: css, html5-audio

I have used the HTML AUDIO tag with CONTROLS to display an audio track.

```
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">  
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Using CSS `audio::-webkit-media-controls-` I figured that many functions can be modified.

However, I couldn't manage to figure out how to disable / hide those 3 dots on the player.

[image]

PS: This helped a lot in disabling / styling the controls with CSS.
However, it was an answer from many years ago, so it didn't include playback speed options.

[Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Comment: Styling those special browser elements is usually unreliable - I would suggest creating+styling your own stand-alone audio controls that uses JavaScript to interact with your hidden `<audio ... >` tag to play, stop, adjust volume, etc.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69100753/2837356

Comment: I am hoping that i wont have to take the route of making a custom player.

Able to control all function of the audio controls, except those 3 dots(menu).
I believe, that video tags have that functionality, wonder why it never made it to audio tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to style html5 audio tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126708/is-it-possible-to-style-html5-audio-tag)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this controlsList: **noplaybackrate**

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate">  
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```